# Как в pandas добавить столбец с данными из списка?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Есть два файла:

1. input_csv_file, в котором есть столбец ['index']
2. input_file_w_address, который представляет собой список из кортежей:
   [(индекс1, адрес1), (индекс2, адрес2)], т.е. на [0] месте стоит
   индекс, на [-1] - адрес

Читаю файлы: (в txt применяю eval, чтобы файл в переменную зашел именно списком кортежей, а не строкой)

```
text_input = open(input_file_w_address, 'r').read()
text_input = eval(text_input)
csv_input = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file)
```

затем хочу:

1. посмотреть в csv_input
2. взять каждое i-тое значение из столбца
   'index'
3. в списке взять каждый y-тый элемент (это будет каждый кортеж)
4. в нем посмотреть на y[0]-элемент и сравнить с i
5. если они равны, взять y[-1] и записать его в новый столбец

```
csv_input['new_address'] = None
for i in csv_input['index']:
    for i in range(csv_input.shape[0]):
        for y in text_input:
            text_input_index = y[0]
            text_input_address = y[-1]
            if i == text_input_index:
                csv_input['new_address'] = text_input_address
```

у меня не получилось. подскажите, где ошибка?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все оказалось гораздо проще:

1. Нам нужно взять список кортежей
2. Определить индексы и (в моем случае) адреса
3. Использовать специальную конструкцию pandas: df.loc

```
for y in text_input:
    text_input_index = y[0]
    text_input_address = y[-1]
    csv_input.loc[csv_input['index'] == int(text_input_index),
                  'new_address'] = text_input_address
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что все может быть ещё проще и решается одним-единственным векторизиванным методом pandas типа join, безо всяких циклов. И вам могли бы наверняка это сказать, если бы вы привели пример исходных данных и желаемого результата. Использование циклов по датафрейму - крайне не эффективная идея.